# How to write to file in test in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, flutter-test, read-write

I want to test a function that resize an image.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

static Future<File?> resizeImage({required File imageFile, int? width, int? height}) async {
    final img.Image? inputImage = img.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());

    if (inputImage != null) {
      final outputImage = img.copyResize(inputImage, width: width, height: height);
      
      final String localPath = await getLocalPath();
      final File outputImageFile = File('$localPath/resizedImage.png')..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodePng(outputImage));
      
      return outputImageFile;
    }
  }
```

Then in test:

```
const String kApplicationSupportPath = 'applicationSupportPath';

class FakePathProviderPlatform extends Fake
    with MockPlatformInterfaceMixin
    implements PathProviderPlatform {

  @override
  Future<String?> getApplicationSupportPath() async {
    return kApplicationSupportPath;
  }
}

setUp(() async {
    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    PathProviderPlatform.instance = FakePathProviderPlatform();
  });

test(
    'given 3000x4000 pixel file - resize to max allowed with & height - verify size restrictions',
    () async {
      const int maxWith = 2160;
      const int maxHeight = 1440;
      
      const String assetPath = 'assets/test_image_gradient_black_white_3000x4000.png';
      final File imageFile = File(assetPath);

      final File resizedImageFile = await ImageUtils.resizeImage(
        imageFile: imageFile,
        maxWidth: maxWith,
        maxHeight: maxHeight,
      );
      final int width = ImageUtils.getWidth(resizedImageFile);
      final int height = ImageUtils.getHeight(resizedImageFile);

      expect(width <= maxWith, true);
      expect(height <= maxHeight, true);
    },
  );
```

I get the following error:

> FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'applicationSupportPath/resizedImage.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

How can I mock path provider so that I can actually write to the path?